# Flink Fencing Errors in K8 HA mode

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using Flink 1.12 and trying to keep job manager in HA over Kubernetes cluster (AKS). I am running 2 job manager and 2 task manager pods.

The problem that I am facing is that the task managers are not able to find the jobmanager leader.

The reason being they are trying to hit the K8 "Service" for jobmanager (which is a clusterIP Service) instead of hitting the pod IP of the leader. Hence sometimes the jobmanager Service will resolve the registration call to the standby jobmanager which makes TaskManger to not be able to find the jobmanager leader.

Here are the contents of the jobmanager-leader file

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "data": {
        "address": "akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/jobmanager_2",
        "sessionId": "ee14c446-82b0-45ab-b470-ee445ddd0e0f"
    },
    "kind": "ConfigMap",
    "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
            "control-plane.alpha.kubernetes.io/leader": "{\"holderIdentity\":\"e6a42a4f-235e-4b97-93c6-40f4b987f56b\",\"leaseDuration\":15.000000000,\"acquireTime\":\"2021-02-16T05:13:37.365000Z\",\"renewTime\":\"2021-02-16T05:22:17.386000Z\",\"leaderTransitions\":105}"
        },
        "creationTimestamp": "2021-02-15T16:13:26Z",
        "labels": {
            "app": "flinktestk8cluster",
            "configmap-type": "high-availability",
            "type": "flink-native-kubernetes"
        },
        "name": "flinktestk8cluster-bc7b6f9aa8b0a111e1c50b10155a85be-jobmanager-leader",
        "namespace": "default",
        "resourceVersion": "46202881",
        "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps/flinktestk8cluster-bc7b6f9aa8b0a111e1c50b10155a85be-jobmanager-leader",
        "uid": "1d5ca6e3-dc7e-4fb7-9fab-c1bbb956cda9"
    }
}
```

Here `flink-jobmanager` is the name of the K8 Service for jobmanager.

Is there a way to fix this? How do I make jobmanager write podIP in the leader file instead of service name?

Here is the exception

```
2021-02-12 06:15:53,849 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor           [] - Registration at ResourceManager failed due to an error
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.exceptions.FencingTokenException: Fencing token not set: Ignoring message RemoteFencedMessage(954fe694bb4d268a2e32b4497e944144, RemoteRpcInvocation(registerTaskExecutor(TaskExecutorRegistration, Time))) sent to akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_0 because the fencing token is null.
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAccept(CompletableFuture.java:661) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniAccept.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:646) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1990) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaInvocationHandler.lambda$invokeRpc$0(AkkaInvocationHandler.java:235) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1990) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$1.onComplete(FutureUtils.java:1044) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:263) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:261) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:191) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:188) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.Executors$DirectExecutionContext.execute(Executors.java:73) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:68) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1(Promise.scala:284) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1$adapted(Promise.scala:284) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:284) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:573) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.dispatch(Endpoint.scala:101) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at akka.remote.EndpointReader$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(Endpoint.scala:999) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at akka.remote.EndpointActor.aroundReceive(Endpoint.scala:458) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.exceptions.FencingTokenException: Fencing token not set: Ignoring message RemoteFencedMessage(954fe694bb4d268a2e32b4497e944144, RemoteRpcInvocation(registerTaskExecutor(TaskExecutorRegistration, Time))) sent to akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_0 because the fencing token is null.
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:67) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:159) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
... 9 more
2021-02-12 06:15:53,849 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor           [] - Pausing and re-attempting registration in 10000 ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you want to give your JobManager pods unique addresses when using standby JobManagers. Hence, you must not configure a service which the components use to communicate with each other. Instead you should start your JobManager pods with the pod IP as its `jobmanager.rpc.address`.

In order to start each JobManager pod with its IP you must not configure a ConfigMap which contains the Flink configuration, because it would be the same configuration for every JobManager pod. Instead you need to add the following snippet to your JobManager deployment:

```
env:
  - name: MY_POD_IP
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: status.podIP
  - name: FLINK_PROPERTIES
    value: |
      jobmanager.rpc.address: ${MY_POD_IP}
```

That way we tell each JobManager pod to use the pod's IP for the `jobmanager.rpc.address` which is also written to the K8s HA service. If this is done, then every K8s HA service user which runs inside of the K8s cluster can find the current leader.

Next you need to configure for all deployments that you want to use the K8s HA service. You can do this via extending the `FLINK_PROPERTIES` env variable:

```
env:
  - name: MY_POD_IP
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: status.podIP
  - name: FLINK_PROPERTIES
    value: |
      jobmanager.rpc.address: ${MY_POD_IP}
      kubernetes.cluster-id: foobar
      high-availability: org.apache.flink.kubernetes.highavailability.KubernetesHaServicesFactory
      high-availability.storageDir: hdfs:///flink/recovery
      restart-strategy: fixed-delay
      restart-strategy.fixed-delay.attempts: 10
```

Adding this to your JobManager pod definition and

```
env:
  - name: FLINK_PROPERTIES
    value: |
      kubernetes.cluster-id: foobar
      high-availability: org.apache.flink.kubernetes.highavailability.KubernetesHaServicesFactory
      high-availability.storageDir: hdfs:///flink/recovery
      restart-strategy: fixed-delay
      restart-strategy.fixed-delay.attempts: 10
```

to your TaskManager deployment should solve the problem.

The full deployment yamls can be found here

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flink-jobmanager
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flink
      component: jobmanager
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flink
        component: jobmanager
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jobmanager
        image: flink:1.12.1
        args: ["jobmanager"]
        env:
          - name: MY_POD_IP
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: status.podIP
          - name: FLINK_PROPERTIES
            value: |
              jobmanager.rpc.address: ${MY_POD_IP}
              kubernetes.cluster-id: foobar
              high-availability: org.apache.flink.kubernetes.highavailability.KubernetesHaServicesFactory
              high-availability.storageDir: file:///flink/recovery
              restart-strategy: fixed-delay
              restart-strategy.fixed-delay.attempts: 10
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6123
          name: rpc
        - containerPort: 6124
          name: blob-server
        - containerPort: 8081
          name: webui
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 6123
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 60
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 9999  # refers to user _flink_ from official flink image, change if necessary
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flink-taskmanager
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flink
      component: taskmanager
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flink
        component: taskmanager
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: taskmanager
        image: flink:1.12.1
        args: ["taskmanager"]
        env:
          - name: FLINK_PROPERTIES
            value: "kubernetes.cluster-id: foobar\n
high-availability: org.apache.flink.kubernetes.highavailability.KubernetesHaServicesFactory\n
high-availability.storageDir: file:///flink/recovery\n
restart-strategy: fixed-delay\n
restart-strategy.fixed-delay.attempts: 10"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6122
          name: rpc
        - containerPort: 6125
          name: query-state
        - containerPort: 6121
          name: metrics
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 6122
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 60
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 9999  # refers to user _flink_ from official flink image, change if necessary
```

Comment: Would I need to remove flink-conf.yaml configmap completely since the properties are being set through env "FLINK_PROPERTIES"?

Comment: Yes, this is required. Unfortunately setting the configuration via `FLINK_PROPERTIES` and a ConfigMap based `flink-conf.yaml` does not play well together.

Comment: So I tried with this configuration but I get ```/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 95: /opt/flink/conf/flink-conf.yaml: No such file or directory```
To solve for it I tried creating empty flink-conf.yaml but I bash into the pod shows that the FLINK_PROPERTIES are not appended into the conf. Also, echo FLINK_PROPERTIES shows ```jobmanager.rpc.address: ${MY_POD_IP}``` so MY_POD_IP was never replaced

Comment: Which Docker image are you running exactly? I would highly recommend using this one https://hub.docker.com/_/flink with version 1.12 or 1.11.

Comment: Accepting the answer since I was able to hack around it by changing the volume mount path. But I am still not able to change the log4j conf. I tried using initContainers but it didn't work

Comment: Can you share the Dockerfile for the image? I am using this https://github.com/apache/flink-docker

Comment: https://github.com/apache/flink-docker should be the correct Dockerfile. The important bit is to not use the ConfigMap backed `flink-conf.yaml` but to use the `flink-conf.yaml` which is included in the Docker image and to customize it via `FLINK_PROPERTIES`.